# Oracle Apex on network

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, listener, oracle-apex

i have install oracle 11g and apex 18.2 in my desktop computer, apex is running successfully in this computer with 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' but unable to run in this desktop ip say 192.168.0.1. i have validate listener i.e

> Listening Endpoints Summary...
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST= HOSTNAME)(PORT=1521)))
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))

my listener in listener.ora is

> LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
> (DESCRIPTION =
> (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
> (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HOSTNAME)(PORT = 1521))
> )   )
>
> DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
>
> apex fail to load and raise 'This site can’t be
> reached192.168.0.1 refused to connect.'

i change the host with ip 192.168.0.1. with;
LOCAL_LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
)
)
listener stat is

> Listening Endpoints Summary...
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=HOSTNAME)(PORT=1521)))
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))

but still it say;

> apex fail to load when and raise 'This site can’t be
> reached192.168.0.1 refused to connect.'

please guide.

Answer (score 0):

> EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS(FALSE);

above statement solve my issue.

refere https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/network.htm#ADMQS171